# JSONObject is not getting converted to String properly

Tags: java, json, string

I am converting JSONObject to String. I am using below code:

```
String decresponse=obj.getFileWithUtil("Files/v3user22.txt");
System.out.println("Decrypted string is "+decresponse);
JSONObject js = JSONObject(decresponse);
System.out.println("JSON Object is "+js.toString());
```

Here, i am getting the value of decresponse from a file since the json is very large. Value of decresponse is:

```
{
    "userid":123456,
    "status":"SUCCESS",
    "name":{
        "firstName":"firstname",
        "lastName":"lastname"
    },
    "dob":"03/02/1993",
    "gender":"M",
    "kycType":"Manual",
    "address":{
        "permanentAddress":{
            "country":"INDIA",
            "street_1":"K-26",
            "street_2":"",
            "city":"North",
            "state":"Delhi",
            "postal_code":"110052",
            "locality":"abc"
        },
        "correspondenceAddress":{
            "country":"INDIA",
            "street_1":"abc",
            "street_2":"abc",
            "city":"ABC",
            "state":"Punjab",
            "postal_code":"111000",
            "locality":"def"
        }
    },
    "docs":[
        {
            "nameOnDoc":"name",
            "verificationStatus":"FAILED",
            "kycNameMatch":"SUCCESS",
            "docCode":"aadhar",
            "docValue":"1898989",
            "submittedAs":"AdditionalDoc"
        },
        {
            "nameOnDoc":"abc",
            "verificationStatus":"NOT_ATTEMPTED",
            "kycNameMatch":"NOT_ATTEMPTED",
            "docCode":"pan",
            "docValue":"KSKA1234F",
            "submittedAs":"AdditionalDoc",
            "expiryDate":"03/02/2018"
        },
        {
            "docCode":"voter",
            "docValue":"CIBPS2107P",
            "submittedAs":"Poi_Poa"
        }
    ],
    "agents":[
        {
            "bankAgentType":"BF",
            "agentBranch":"nodia",
            "agentDesignation":"agent manager",
            "agentEmpcode":"1010111",
            "custId":"119990",
            "agentId":"",
            "agencyType":"CFA",
            "agencyName":"internal"
        },
        {
            "bankAgentType":"BC",
            "agentBranch":"nodia",
            "agentDesignation":"agent manager",
            "agentEmpcode":"",
            "custId":"119999",
            "agentId":"MORPHO-1782",
            "agencyType":"VA",
            "agencyName":"morpho"
        }
    ],
    "relatives":[
        {
            "relationShip":"FATHER",
            "firstName":"firstname",
            "lastName":"lastname"
        },
        {
            "relationShip":"MOTHER",
            "firstName":"firstname",
            "lastName":"lastname"
        }
    ],
    "useKycDetails":"UNDER_REVIEW",
    "amlflags":{
        "sanction":"N",
        "pep":"N"
    },
    "walletflags":{
        "upgraded":"1",
        "updated":"1",
        "blocked":"0"
    },
    "suspended":"false",
    "aadhar_type1_check":"FAILED",
    "aadhar_kyc_name_check":"SUCCESS",
    "aadharSubmittedAs":"AdditionalDoc",
    "aadharVerified":"false",
    "panSubmittedAs":"AdditionalDoc",
    "panVerified":"false",
    "maritalStatus":"MARRIED",
    "profession":"PRIVATE_SECTOR_JOB",
    "nationality":"INDIAN",
    "kycVerificationDate":"04/01/2017",
    "declarationPlace":"Delhi",
    "dmsInfos":[
        {
            "type":"",
            "dmsid":""
        }
    ],
    "aadharAuthCode":"56bd65db0dbc4b2a848841a44eabb54e",
    "agriculturalIncome":"100000",
    "nonAgriculturalIncome":"50000",
    "seedingStatus":"consent_given"
}
```

But, on converting the json object to string the value comes as below:

```
{
    "panVerified":"false",
    "gender":"M",
    "userid":123456,
    "panSubmittedAs":"AdditionalDoc",
    "aadharAuthCode":"56bd65db0dbc4b2a848841a44eabb54e",
    "docs":[
        {
            "kycNameMatch":"SUCCESS",
            "verificationStatus":"FAILED",
            "nameOnDoc":"name",
            "docCode":"aadhar",
            "docValue":"1898989",
            "submittedAs":"AdditionalDoc"
        },
        {
            "expiryDate":"03/02/2018",
            "kycNameMatch":"NOT_ATTEMPTED",
            "verificationStatus":"NOT_ATTEMPTED",
            "nameOnDoc":"abc",
            "docCode":"pan",
            "docValue":"KSKA1234F",
            "submittedAs":"AdditionalDoc"
        },
        {
            "docCode":"voter",
            "docValue":"CIBPS2107P",
            "submittedAs":"Poi_Poa"
        }
    ],
    "aadhar_type1_check":"FAILED",
    "aadharSubmittedAs":"AdditionalDoc",
    "useKycDetails":"UNDER_REVIEW",
    "kycVerificationDate":"04/01/2017",
    "kycType":"Manual",
    "profession":"PRIVATE_SECTOR_JOB",
    "address":{
        "permanentAddress":{
            "country":"INDIA",
            "street_1":"K-26",
            "city":"North",
            "street_2":"",
            "locality":"abc",
            "state":"Delhi",
            "postal_code":"110052"
        },
        "correspondenceAddress":{
            "country":"INDIA",
            "street_1":"abc",
            "city":"ABC",
            "street_2":"abc",
            "locality":"def",
            "state":"Punjab",
            "postal_code":"111000"
        }
    },
    "nonAgriculturalIncome":"50000",
    "seedingStatus":"consent_given",
    "dmsInfos":[
        {
            "dmsid":"",
            "type":""
        }
    ],
    "relatives":[
        {
            "firstName":"firstname",
            "lastName":"lastname",
            "relationShip":"FATHER"
        },
        {
            "firstName":"firstname",
            "lastName":"lastname",
            "relationShip":"MOTHER"
        }
    ],
    "suspended":"false",
    "agents":[
        {
            "agentId":"",
            "agentEmpcode":"1010111",
            "custId":"119990",
            "agentBranch":"nodia",
            "agentDesignation":"agent manager",
            "bankAgentType":"BF",
            "agencyType":"CFA",
            "agencyName":"internal"
        },
        {
            "agentId":"MORPHO-1782",
            "agentEmpcode":"",
            "custId":"119999",
            "agentBranch":"nodia",
            "agentDesignation":"agent manager",
            "bankAgentType":"BC",
            "agencyType":"VA",
            "agencyName":"morpho"
        }
    ],
    "amlflags":{
        "sanction":"N",
        "pep":"N"
    },
    "aadhar_kyc_name_check":"SUCCESS",
    "nationality":"INDIAN",
    "dob":"03/02/1993",
    "walletflags":{
        "upgraded":"1",
        "blocked":"0",
        "updated":"1"
    },
    "name":{
        "firstName":"firstname",
        "lastName":"lastname"
    },
    "aadharVerified":"false",
    "maritalStatus":"MARRIED",
    "status":"SUCCESS",
    "declarationPlace":"Delhi",
    "agriculturalIncome":"100000"
}
```

Why am I getting different values?

Comment: Please format those JSON objects as they are hard to read. You don't want to make it harder for folks to answer and help, do you?

Comment: formatted now..

Comment: JSONObject class is there in many libraries, which one you are referring to ?

Comment: What is different? All the data appears to be the same, you should never rely on object order in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting different values

Those values are not *that* different. They simply have `key:value` pairs in different order.

JSON structure holds `key:value` pairs where `key`s are unique. In most cases order of keys is not important so classes like `org.json.JSONObject` are storing them in internal `HashMap` which doesn't preserve insertion order (but allows quick access to values).

When `toString()` is invoked internally it builds String using that HashMap iterator, so order depends on amount of keys and their hashes, not insertion order.

---

If you want to preserve order consider using other libraries like [gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md). Your parsing could look like:

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject js = jsonParser.parse(decresponse).getAsJsonObject();
```

and `js.toString()` would result in
`{"userid":123456,"status":"SUCCESS","name":{"firstName":"firstname", ...` which seems to be what you ware after.

Comment: is there any other way of storing the json string into a JSON Object and then converting again it to a string while maintaining the order ?

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly fine. I have one more doubt. Does gson provide support for JSONArray also. If I like to convert JSONArray into string.

Comment: @PrashantMudgal gosn is JSON library allowing us to do many things with JSON. It wouldn't be used world-wide if there was no support for JSON arrays :) So yes, there is`JsonArray` class there.